# Is there a built-in way to use inline C code in Python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cython, inline

Even if `numba`, `cython` (and especially `cython.inline`) exist, in some cases, it would be interesting to have inline C code in Python.

**Is there a built-in way (in Python standard library) to have inline C code?**

PS: [scipy.weave](https://github.com/scipy/weave) used to provide this, but it's Python 2 only.

Comment: I just want to add that this "inline code" asked here has little to do with the keyword `inline` in C99.

Comment: @YiFei Yes, I'm speaking about having inline C code inside Python code, in the same way you can do inline ASM inside C code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly in the Python standard library, probably not. But it's possible to have something very close to inline C in Python with the `cffi` module (`pip install cffi`).

Here is an example, inspired by [this article](http://sametmax.com/introduction-aux-extensions-python-avec-cffi/) and [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1wyj7e/inline_c_code_in_python/), showing how to implement a factorial function in Python + "inline" C:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.set_source("_test", """
long factorial(int n) {
    long r = n;
    while(n > 1) {
        n -= 1;
        r *= n;
    }
    return r;
}
""")
ffi.cdef("""long factorial(int);""")
ffi.compile()
from _test import lib     # import the compiled library
print(lib.factorial(10))  # 3628800
```

Notes:

- `ffi.set_source(...)` defines the actual C source code
- `ffi.cdef(...)` is the equivalent of the `.h` header file
- you can of course add some cleaning code after, if you don't need the compiled library at the end (however, `cython.inline` does the same and the compiled .pyd files are not cleaned by default, [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUr5w.png))
- this quick inline use is particularly useful during a *prototyping* / development phase. Once everything is ready, you can separate the build (that you do only once), and the rest of the code which imports the pre-compiled library

It seems too good to be true, but it seems to work!

Comment: `cffi` is not in the Python standard library, so this does not satisfy the constraints you set out in your question.

Comment: Also, the `_test` module you're generating may not actually be importable (depending on `sys.path`), and you're going to leave a bunch of generated extension modules lying around in any directory you run this code in. `cffi` is not intended to be used like this - the interface you're using is intended to be run in advance, during a "build step", producing an extension module that can then be distributed with your code and imported many times, without regenerating it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica If you look at how `cython.inline` does, it's the same, it "leaves a bunch of generated extension modules", see your `C:\Users\User\.cython\inlin` folder on Windows ;) See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUr5w.png  (long after the execution of `inline` was done).

Comment: Yeah, but you're generating your `_test` module in the current working directory, not in a dedicated area you can safely leave a bunch of junk lying around in. The current working directory isn't even guaranteed to be on `sys.path` (and adding it to `sys.path` when it's not carries its own bag of issues).

Comment: I added a note in my answer @user2357112supportsMonica to clarify that, of course, this approach is particularly useful when prototyping / developing. At the end, when the code is mature, of course, you want to separate compilation/building (done only once), and the rest of the code which imports the precompiled library. Still, during prototyping (and not production), this kind of solution speeds up the workflow *a lot*.

Comment: I can definitely see it making prototyping more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for having mentioned this important aspect @user2357112supportsMonica (I thought it was obvious, but in fact it had to be added in the answer, it wasn't clear in my initial answer).

Comment: Please note that the output in the comment is correct but you are overflowing your integers in the c code.
The factorial of 30 is even not possible to represent in a unsigned long long.
fac(30) = 265252859812191058636308480000000